# explain what is happening in Proc Sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

```
 select Name into :Dataset1-:Dataset%trim(%left(&DatasetNum)) from MEM;
```

I am not able to interpret what is happening here in this statement can anyone give me an explanation. 
I understand this stament

```
select count(Name) into :DatasetNum from MEM
```

But not the above one.

Answer (score 3):

It is attempting to use the value of the macro variable DATASETNUM as the upper bound on the macro variable names that are being created by the SELECT statement. Because the previous variable was created with leading spaces the `%LEFT()` macro is called to remove them. The call to the macro `%trim()` is not needed as trailing spaces would not cause any trouble.

It is much easier to just build the macro variable array first and then set the counter variable from the value of the automatic macro variable SQLOBS.  Plus then it will not have the leading blanks.

```
select name into :Dataset1- from mem ;
%let DatasetNum=&sqlobs;
```

If you have an older version of SAS that doesn't support the new `:varname-` syntax then just use a large value for the upper bound. SAS will only create the number of macro variables it needs.

```
select name into :Dataset1-:Dataset99999 from mem;
```

Comment: I guess that :varname- syntax is new in 9.4?  Never seen it before!  Nice.

Answer (score 1):

This is creating an array of SAS macro variables (DATASET1, DATASET2, DATASET3) etc, populated from the Name column of the MEM dataset.

It is analagous to:

```
data _null_;
  set MEM;
  call symputx(cats('Dataset',_n_),Name);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, But can you explain what is the meaning of     'code'  Dataset1-:Dataset%trim(%left(&DatasetNum))  'code'

Comment: As per @Tom's answer - the %trim / %left functions strip the blanks to ensure the statement resolves like "Dataset1-:DatasetX", instead of "Dataset1-:Dataset  X" (which is a syntax error).  The DatasetNum variable is acting (in this case) as an upperbound for the array of macro variables being created.

Comment: Thank you, Now I understand. I was confused by the - nest to the colon. But now I get it